# Voltage between two points of a square contour in a magnetic field

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism

[image]

a,d,R is given. Current of infinitely long wire is \$ i(t)=I \cos(\omega t) \$

- I get the flux
- derive it over time
- what to do with R?

The solution in the book is:
$$V=-((µ0*I*a*\omega*ln(d+a/d))/(20*pi))*sin(\omega*t)$$

Ignoring Rs you get same similar, \$2\pi\$ instead \$20\pi\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law about induction speaks about a closed path around a magnetic field, but using conductive material, you should think of a small gap in the path. The voltage can be measured at this gap, see left sketch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu83la.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If there's no gap and the wire is a superconductor (Rs=0), you have a short circuit. Current will flow, but you will not measure any voltage anywhere. (Well, things happen then...)

In reality, the wire *has* a resistance. Calculate the induced voltage, and via the resistance, you get the current flowing. This is sketched in the right figure. As you can already see, the voltage measured between the two legs should be half the supply/induced voltage.

Comment: So current is equal induced voltage over total resistance. Do I multiply that current with the upper( or lower) resistances and add that to the half of induced voltage?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. I don't fully understand your second, but just have a look at the right figure. How would you calculate the voltage there? Now, there is no voltage source, but voltage is induced in the loop. It's just the same.

Comment: induced voltage is equal to the upper result only 2pi instead of 20. How do I get to 20? I calculate the current and do the kirchhoff's law? Thanks for answering

Comment: What's the value of Rs? All parameters appear in your formula as such, but Rs does not.

Comment: No value, just R, it cancels probably somewhere.